# Spring Contracts How to create a matcher for x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

**Problem:**

spring-cloud-contracts version: *3.1.0*

Having a Contract

```
 request:
  method: POST
  url: /some/url
  headers:
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  body: a=123&b=345&c=567&d=
  matchers:
    url:
      regex: "/[^/]+/some/url"
    headers: [
      { key: Authorization, regex: .+ },
    ]
    body: [
      { path: "$.a", type: "by_equality", value: "123" }
    ]

response:
  status: 200
  ...........
```

I want to have a response when a=123 and no matter what are other values. By this way I have

```
Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
POST                                                       | POST
[regex] /[^/]+/some/url                                    | /some/url
                                                           |
Content-Type [matches] : .+                                | Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
                                                           |
a=123&b=345&c=567&d=null                                   | a=123&b=123&c=567&d=null                                  <<<<< Body does not match
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Question**: Official documentation very well described how to deal with incoming JSON, but I didn't find how to specify matcher for this concrete case (having x-www-form-urlencoded)?

**UPDATE** Since it recognized body as a JSON I've changed it but result is the same.

Comment: You're using the application/x-www-form-urlencoded but this is really a json, right? So SCC has no idea that it should parse the body in a JSON format and it's doing an exact equality check. Why won't you use the JSON content type instead?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak it's not a JSON. It's application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I didn't find the way, how to provide body for such a type, so I've tried to do it like in my example. Unfortunately, I can't change type of data, so let me little bit correct my question. How to provide in a proper way body for mentioned type, and how to provide matcher for situation I've described. Thanks in advance.